# How to add a button to every row in MUI X DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I can't add a button into every row of MUI X `DataGrid`.
I have an MUI X `DataGrid` which I render like this:

```
<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
```

I have added into the columns variable 'actions' column where the button should be rows are just a data object I get from the props. How can I add a button to every row (for editing the row)? I have tried mapping the data array but it is not possible to add a JSX button into every object of data.

Comment: Can you add some code that can be used to recreate the issue? You can also try to produce a runnable functioning program that presents the issue using http://codesandbox.io

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-feistel-cg9wq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can add your custom component by overriding [`GridColDef.renderCell`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#rendering-cells) method and return whatever element you want.

The example below displays an action column that renders a single button in each row. When clicking the button, it alerts the current row data in JSON string:

```js
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
  {
    field: "action",
    headerName: "Action",
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      const onClick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation(); // don't select this row after clicking

        const api: GridApi = params.api;
        const thisRow: Record<string, GridCellValue> = {};

        api
          .getAllColumns()
          .filter((c) => c.field !== "__check__" && !!c)
          .forEach(
            (c) => (thisRow[c.field] = params.getValue(params.id, c.field))
          );

        return alert(JSON.stringify(thisRow, null, 4));
      };

      return <Button onClick={onClick}>Click</Button>;
    }
  },
];
```

[image: Edit 64331095/cant-add-a-button-to-every-row-in-material-ui-table]

Comment: not sure how to use it can u do it in this code? https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-feistel-cg9wq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Just copy the `colDef` with the custom `renderCell` property in it. You can see in your demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/64331095cant-add-a-button-to-every-row-in-material-ui-table64331367noredirect1comment11375713464331367-juizs?file=/src/App.js) @NiTai

Comment: When I add a method to the button which updates the state I get maxiumum depth exceeded error. Does anyone else experience this?

Comment: `Module '"@material-ui/data-grid"' has no exported member 'ColDef'.`

Comment: @fuat if you're using newer package, replace `ColDef` with `GridColDef`. See [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/releases/tag/v4.0.0-alpha.21) changelog (PR #1069)

Comment: I replaced it but now: `Type '(params: GridCellParams) => void' is not assignable to type '(params: GridCellParams) => ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.`

Comment: @fuat I've updated the codesandbox's  `@material-ui/data-grid` to the latest version and fixed the type issue in older version. About your particular problem, it seems like your `renderCell` doesn't return anything. It should return a react component like `<button/>` for example. Please fork my codesandbox and put your link here if you still have any problem

Comment: Thank you for your effort but there is a little issue due to Typescript: `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.  TS7053` this is about `thisRow` variable.

Comment: @fuat Replace `const thisRow` with `const thisRow: Record<string, GridCellValue>`. See my updated codesandbox

Comment: You are awesome, thanks a lot, I can not find the types,

Comment: So in such a case how can set the row value in the state?

Comment: @fuat Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. `GridCellValue` and all other public types can be found in `"@material-ui/data-grid"` module.

Comment: I want to open a dialog when clicking the button

Comment: @fuat Can you open a new question with more detail about what you want. This chat is getting rather long.

Comment: This is a typescript code. Can you please include the code for javascript or jsx file

Answer (score 41):

Just came across this.

What you need to do is include a renderCell method in your columns array.

```
 const columns = [
    {
        field: 'col1',
        headerName: 'Name 1',
        width: 150,
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    },
    {
        field: 'col2',
        headerName: 'Name 2',
        width: 300,
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    },
    {
        field: 'col3',
        headerName: 'Name 3',
        width: 300,
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    },
    {
        field: 'col4',
        headerName: 'Name 4',
        width: 100,
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    },
    {
        field: 'col5',
        headerName: 'Name 5',
        width: 150,
        ***renderCell: renderSummaryDownloadButton,***
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    },
    {
        field: 'col6',
        headerName: 'Name 6',
        width: 150,
        ***renderCell: renderDetailsButton,***
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    },
]
```

In the above I am rendering a Button inside columns 5 and 6 which will appear on every populated row.

Above that you can have a function which creates and returns a Button from Material-ui.

```
 const renderDetailsButton = (params) => {
        return (
            <strong>
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    size="small"
                    style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}
                    onClick={() => {
                        parseName(params.row.col6)
                    }}
                >
                    More Info
                </Button>
            </strong>
        )
    }
```

Comment: This should be the default answer. Much more concise and uses the new API instead of the old method.

Answer (score 13):

According to **MUI X v5** `params.getValue` method is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version, Instead, you can access the current row data from `params.row`.

```
{
  field: 'action',
  headerName: 'Action',
  width: 180,
  sortable: false,
  disableClickEventBubbling: true,
  
  renderCell: (params) => {
      const onClick = (e) => {
        const currentRow = params.row;
        return alert(JSON.stringify(currentRow, null, 4));
      };
      
      return (
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="warning" size="small" onClick={onClick}>Edit</Button>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="error" size="small" onClick={onClick}>Delete</Button>
        </Stack>
      );
  },
}
```

Answer (score 8):

While @NearHuscarl's response answers the question perfectly, I'd like to post a TypeScript example:

```
  const onClick = () => {
    const api: GridApi = params.api;
    const fields = api
      .getAllColumns()
      .map((c) => c.field)
      .filter((c) => c !== "__check__" && !!c);
    const thisRow: any = {};

    fields.forEach((f) => {
      thisRow[f] = params.getValue(params.id, f);
    });

    return alert(JSON.stringify(thisRow, null, 4));
  };

  return <Button onClick={onClick}>Click</Button>;
```

Also note, I changed the getValue call. (included the row id)

Comment: Thanks for this. `getValue` needs two params and I was kinda stuck there

Comment: Is GridAPI only for paid MUI?

Comment: I'd have to check, but I think we're using it successfully in a non-paid MUI project.

Comment: @EduardoFigueiredo The pro version is paid and has more features, but its base form is free and sufficient for many purposes.

Comment: Can you please convert the above code to javascript

Answer (score 2):

The currently top voted answer is outdated as of v5, because the [new GridRowParams interface](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-row-params/) contains the actual row as a parameter, making the manual filtering from the GridApi unnecessary and unpractical.

Using this with `renderCell` can be as simple as

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
  {
    field: "action",
    headerName: "Action",
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: ({ row }: Partial<GridRowParams>) =>
      <Button onClick={() => yourActionFunction(row)}>
        Action
      </Button>,
  },
]
```

in TypeScript or

```
const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
  {
    field: "action",
    headerName: "Action",
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: ({ row }) =>
      <Button onClick={() => yourActionFunction(row)}>
        Action
      </Button>,
  },
]
```

in plain JavaScript.

Comment: ^^Current answer a/o 9/23, is there a way to put multiple buttons under the same col?

Comment: @MX313 You can put any component(s) inside the renderCell callback, so just put multiple buttons each with its own handler.