# Adding HTML element inside a object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, object

I'm using this array state to render Infos on a table:

[image: State used to render infos on table]

[image: Table rendering levelFilteredPlayers state info]

As you guys can see, i need to put a copy button on every row of the table, but i tried inserting the HTML directly to the object it self, but it failed:

[image: Trying to add html directly to the object attribute]

[image: HTML not showing the element correctly]

What can I do to show this copy button on every row of the table?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You table component is converting the collumn value toString. Which library are you using to render that table?

Comment: I'm using MaterialUI DataGrid

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331095/how-to-add-a-button-to-every-row-in-material-ui-table about how to implement custom cell renderer

Comment: add sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for debugging is great.

Comment: Can you guys help me? I dont figured it out how to do it with the answer from @uke, heres the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-t3yzd?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
renderCell: (ValueFormatterParams) => {
  <a href="#">Oi </a>; // you are missing return statement
}
```

should be:

```
renderCell: (ValueFormatterParams) => {
  return (<a href="#">Oi </a>); 
}
```

or:

```
 renderCell: (ValueFormatterParams) => ( <a href="#">Oi </a>)
```

EDIT: Getting data from row:

```
  copyHanle = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
  }
  
  //...
  render() {
   const columns = [
      //...
      renderCell: (ValueFormatterParams) => {
         const {row} = ValueFormatterParams;
         return (
            <CopyToClipboard
              text={row.name}
              onCopy={() => this.setState({ copied: true })}
             >
             <button>Copy</button>
          </CopyToClipboard>)
    }
   ]
   //...
  }
```

See: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/#render-cell

Comment: I am happy to help.

Comment: can you help me with one more thing? im trying to render the button on each row so i can copy the nickname from the user of the row, but im having problems, because all buttons are being rendered on each row, as you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-t3yzd?file=/src/App.js  
I tried with forEach too but it didnt work  
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, see my edit. Is this what you are trying to get?

Comment: Sorry. I sent the wrong sandbox link. Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-rgb-0qhhu?file=/src/App.js line 135. for debugging, use world gentebra, elder druid, min level 8 highest 1000, you will see that its generating every row button on every cell, i need to render only the specific button on each cell. right now if i have 50 registers, it wil render 50 copy button on each cell, containing the button of each register

Comment: You don't need the map function, see the edit, also from ValueFormatterParams you can get the user data. Try console.log(ValueFormatterParams), and you will see the data you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help